# overlapping div is covering image and make it unclickable

Tags: css

I have a div that is absolutely positioned so I can place it overlapping an image. the problem is that the empty part of the div is making the image beneath it unclickable. in IE the image is still clickable but in FF or chrome its not/

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to the image. Here's an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2750416</title>
        <style>
            #overlap {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 61px;
                background: pink;
            }
            img {
                position: relative; /* Without it, the image disappears "behind" div */
                float: right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlap">Overlap</div>
        <img src="http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png" onclick="alert('Clickable!')">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix this through CSS alone. The easiest way is to set the div onclick event to the same function as your image onclick.

Comment: well what does your image onclick function look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS4 experimental feature `pointer-events:none` on your absolute element. Problem with this feature is that it doesn't work in all browsers, only firefox and chrome as far as i know. 
Just sharing a bit of information :)